# Not able to telnet sql port 1433 locally or remotely

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I need to connect to a SQL server 2000 from SQL server 2008. but I can not connect to it.
It says me server name or instance are incorrect.
error message:

```
Cannot connect to dpsobhanxxx-xxx.

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)
```

however when I run `telnet 127.0.0.1 1433` in the computer running SQL server 2000 it tells me connection failed. 
I started telnet in windows services. 
when I run `netstat -an` there is no `1433 port`.

I enabled TCP/IP port in SQL server Client network utility with 1433 port. but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days I found the solution so I'll Share it here:
Just upgrade your SQL server 2000 to `SQL server 2000 SP3`

Comment: Oh man - that's pretty bad that you had an unpatched 2000 server running!

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewalls - on both computers and between them (if any).

If this port is blocked, the behavior you are seeing is exactly what I would expect.

Comment: Firewall on both computers are off

Comment: @Raymond - and between them? Have you enabled TCP/IP connections through the SQL Server Configuration Manager?

Comment: In sql server 2008 from configuration manager tcp/ip is enabled and in SQL 2000 from Client network utility I enabled TCP/IP with 1433 port

Comment: @Raymond - Have you restarted the service?

Comment: Please help me I don't know what to do

Comment: @Raymond - I don't know what else to try. Sorry.

Comment: @Odded I found the solution: I upgraded SQL server 2000 to `SQL server 2000 SP3` and I could connect to it. thanks for your help